# Heatmap matplotlib strange blanks

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

I have been trying to do a heatmap in matplotlib from data that looks like:

x y z

where x and y are the coordinates of cells and z is the density/intensity.

I don't know why there are blank lines in the generated figure (see below).

[image: View figure]

My code looks like:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.interpolate import griddata

dat = np.loadtxt('cym-sqdens_2.dat', dtype=float)
X_dat = dat[:,0]
Y_dat = dat[:,1]
Z_dat = dat[:,2]

X, Y, Z, = np.array([]), np.array([]), np.array([])
for i in range(len(X_dat)):
        X = np.append(X, X_dat[i])
        Y = np.append(Y, Y_dat[i])
        Z = np.append(Z, Z_dat[i])
        
xi = np.linspace(X.min(), X.max(), 1000)
yi = np.linspace(Y.min(), Y.max(), 1000)

zi = griddata((X, Y), Z, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')

zmin = 0.0
zmax = 436.0
zi[(zi<zmin) | (zi>zmax)] = None

CS = plt.contourf(xi, yi, zi, 15, cmap=plt.cm.rainbow,
                  vmax=zmax, vmin=zmin)
plt.rcParams["axes.grid"] = False
plt.colorbar()  
plt.show()
```

Comment: The blank spots seem to originate from `zi[(zi<zmin) | (zi>zmax)] = None`. Maybe you can just leave out that line? Then the "invalid" values will get the same color as the highest (or lowest) value of the colorbar. Possibly the cubic interpolation creates values outside of the original range of values.  Note that you could also call `plt.tricontourf` directly with the original X, Y and Z arrays.

Comment: Also note that `X = np.append(X, X_dat[i])` is horribly slow. Just write `X = np.array(dat[:,0])`